ensure connection inside generator function is closed by caller
Today, while programming, I found myself managing a resource (ssh connection) inside a generator function, something similar to the following:
#I decided to use a generator to avoid looping through the list of fnames 2 times

def _yield_fname(host_address, usr, pwd, datapath):
    with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh_client:

        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(host, username=usr, password=pwd)
        
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(
            'find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n"'
        )
        for line in stdout:
            yield fname

def get_foos():

    foos= []
    for fname in self._yield_fname(self.FOO_PATH):
        foos.append(Foo.from_fname(fname))
    
    return foos

def get_bars():

    bars= []
    for fname in self._yield_fname(self.FOO_PATH):
        bars.append(Bar.from_fname(fname))
    
    return bars

In my case, I plan to always consume yield_fname's generator from start to finish, so that the connection is always closed.
However, my concern is that someone (e.g., future me) might use the generator without fully consuming it thus leaving the connection open.
Is there a way to make it evident that the generator should be closed after usage, even if not fully consumed?

I think it's relatively common to use context managers inside generator functions.

You can't prevent it, but what would be the alternative? It wouldn't make sense to create a new connection each time through the loop. I think if the caller breaks out of the loop the generator will become garbage, and that will cause the context manager to exit.

I'd consider refactoring this into two functions: the first one - iterator - accepting client as a parameter, and the second one with a context manager providing that client. This will make lifetimes much more explicit: the generator cannot be used when the client goes out of scope, and everything will be closed at some well-known point. It will also reduce your testing burden - such dependency injection eliminates many patterns where you'd use mocking otherwise. Generator wasn't exhausted? Fine, everything still got closed promptly.

@STerliakov so you're suggesting decorating _yield_fname with @contextmanager, then extracting the iteration part into a different function in order to separate concerns, did I get it right?

Not exactly - I mean keeping your _yield_fname as written, except that it receives ssh_client as a parameter and has no with stmt. Then you have a separate function read_fnames that does with SSHClient() as client: return list(self._yield_fname(client, ...)) - now you have only one place that does resource management and no longer depend on the iterator consumption, plus such function guarantees it's consumed entirely. And your get_foos then just calls read_fnames without knowing anything about its resource management.


is it bad practice to manage a resource inside a generator function in this way?

IMO no, that's pretty normal usage

Should I worry about someone (e.g. future me) using the generator without fully consuming it and leaving the connection open?

Probably not, but it's a possible concern. I'm fairly certain that (as written) the context manager will "live" so long as the generator hasn't been exhausted or garbage collected.
I generally wouldn't worry about it though, it's kind of a performance/resource edge case, and exacting performance and resource management isn't a high priority in large majority of Python use-cases.

is there a way to prevent that?

You can create the context outside of the generator, passing it in. Even if the generator isn't exhausted, you can still exit the context.
gen = None  # even if we keep generator from being garbage collected
found = None
with get_resource() as res:
    gen = build_generator(res)
    for item in gen:
        if desired(item):
            found = item
            break  # incomplete iteration

print(item)

